# MVC3,how to validate form with modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I am working on MVC3, razor views.
I have a form with lots of input text boxes with validations. The problem is that there is not enough space to show inline validation message against each textbox. I have been told instead that I should use modal dialog boxes for the validations.

I would like to know the best way to do this.

I tried using the keyup events for the texbox to validate data. But it doesn't seem to work for copy and paste scenario.There must be a  better way to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing handlers for the keyup events, you could also write handlers for the copy and paste events and use the same validation routines that you have in place. I know jQuery 1.4 and above has support for cut,copy, and paste events.